# Generating shared secret random permutation

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs, pseudo-random-generator, commitments

There are three blind card game players. Each player does not trust any other, even prejudicing other two players may not be blind, or there may be others in the room, peeking at their cards.

In order to protect from glimpsing their hands, each player puts each of his cards into separate locked box, each box having its own key. Owners know which box holds which card, while others don't. In other words, players make a HMAC-SHA256 hashes of strings in form `'card_value:commonly_agreed_public_salt'` with random key for each card, and then announce each other list of the hashes they posess.

When player makes a move, he moves one of locked box he owns to the middle of table and discloses the key, so everyone sees what card is inside. In other words, when making a move, player discloses HMAC key used to hash card value, and card value itself. This way other players can verify that this card was really owned by him.

I hope this approach makes it impossible for all the observers in the room, if any, to get any information, other than count of cards in posession of each player, am I missing something?

Now I'm stuck in how should I design retrieval of additional or initial cards from deck. I guess I should make use of preseeded PRNG similar to Mersenne Twister, to avoid duplicates, but how to make seed both secret, so one cannot simply traverse all the deck to know all the cards in the future, or to know which cards were picked by other players, and shared, so everyone will get same results while grabbing cards from deck.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Mental Poker? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach makes getting information other than count of cards in

possession of each player at least as hard as breaking the [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family)ness of HMAC.

To make it information-theoretically impossible "for all the ... each player",

$\;\;$ if different `card_value`s have different lengths then use

$\;\;$ `SHA256(commonly_agreed_public_salt:card_value)`

$\;\;$ instead of `card_value` for what follows

$\;\;$ at the beginning, each player chooses a [strong extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Strong_extractors) whose output length is  equal to the length of

$\;\;$ each `card_value`, chooses a random `seed` for that extractor, and sends both of those to everyone

$\;\;$ (those choices can be reused)

$\;\;$ players compute `SHA256(commonly_agreed_public_salt:secret_random_value)`

$\;\;$ and `Extract(secret_random_value,seed) xor card_value`

$\;\;$ with independently chosen `secret_random_value` for each card,

$\;\;$ and then announce to each other the list of the pairs they possess

.
For retrieval of additional cards from the deck, you need to use

multi-party computation; specifically mental poker protocols.

(as already mentioned by bmm6o)

Comment: I've read your answer several times, and now I hope I mostly understood it. To your opinion, is `Extract(value, seed) := SHA256(seed:value)` with `seed` being at least 512 bit, applicable?

Comment: In my opinion, it's not, since part of the point is that the hiding property should be unconditional. $\:$ By following [this proof](http://www.math.sc.edu/~cooper/math778C/leftover.pdf) of the [Leftover Hash Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftover_hash_lemma), one can see the (non necessarily cryptographic) hash family $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ only needs to be universal (not necessarily pairwise independent), so one can let `Extract(value,seed)` be a truncation of `left_half_of_value + (right_half_of_value * seed)` where + and * are over a [finite field](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/juan.pdf). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: In my previous comment, "a truncation" should be replaced with "the least significant bits". $\hspace{.89 in}$

Comment: well... did I understand you correctly that using cryptographic hash function will also work, but it's just less efficient compared to pure GF math? I'm afraid I'll horribly fail with implementing it myself, just because I know nothing about this field of math, and that's why I'd prefer at least use widely known algorithm.

Comment: and if doing `left_half + (right_half * seed)`, is it really enough? E.g. isn't that *too simple*? And what size of finite field should I use? Sorry for dumb questions.

Comment: One can heuristically expect using a cryptographic hash function to also work. $\:$ I have no clue which is more efficient. $\:$ You can also replace "over a finite field" with "[modulo a prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)". $\:$ (The chooser can test primality with [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin), and no one else needs to care about whether the modulus is actually prime.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, that really is enough, one can google [paper's about that general idea](https://www.google.com/#q=Leftover+Hash+Lemma+universal+hash). $\:$ However, if one wants to reduce the amount of per-card randomness needed at the cost of increasing the amount of reusable randomness needed, then you can get that by using _slightly_ more complicated extractors. $\:$ (Namely, you split the value into more pieces and multiply some or all of them by different parts of the seed.) $\:$ I'll figure out what size of finite field you should use when I get back to my computer much later today. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If you use a field with 2^n elements, then n must be at least the lengths of the `card_value`s, and if it is then the observers' ability to get information from a particular pair of hashes will be at most 3*(2^((254-n)/3)). $\:$ If you use a field with p elements and the `card_value`s are L bits long and you choose `left_half` and `right_half` uniformly from {0,1,2,3,...,p-1} rather than as random bit strings, then the observers' ability to get information from a particular pair of hashes will be less than (3*(2^((255-[number of bits in p])/3)))+((2^(L-1))/p). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! One last question — am I free to split value into left and right halves arbitrarily, or swap left and right halves? If yes, can I just select arbitrary bitmask and do something like `(left_half & mask) + ((right_half & ~mask) * seed)`?

Comment: If you use a field with 2^n elements, then you can split `value` into two halves arbitrarily (or swap left and right halves). $\:$ If you use a field with 2^n elements and directly split `value`, then there's no point in using a mask, since you would already have the two halves $\:$ If you use a field with p elements, then you should split `value` according to how it was chosen (as I mentioned in my previous comment), although you can swap left and right halves. $\;\;\;\;$